# Data Encryption in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an iOS app where I need Triple DES Encrytpion. While browsing online I came across this statement

> If you put your own encryption code into your app, you will need to get an export license for it before your app can be approved by Apple. If you use the encryption routines provided by Apple, this isn't necessary.

I would just like to know for the integration of Triple DES Encryption do I need an export license ?If yes, then what is the procedure ?

Comment: and are you using encryption routines provided by Apple?

Comment: encryption routines ??? I will be using CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h .

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not about apple, this is about USA laws. If you are using system libraries (`CommonCryptor`) everything is okey. If you are adding your own cryptographics frameworks, you'll need an export license.

Comment: Just curious, how do you know that using `CommonCryptor` is fine?